# distinction of naming convention between "value" and "val"?

Tags: naming-conventions

I saw one script using "value" in class constructor's parameter 
BUT "val" as function parameter.

```
constructor(value){}

push(val){}
```

Is it a personal preference, or convention?

Comment: It is personal preference

Answer (score 0):

Its normal to use val in place of value as a short version.There are no such conventions. When it comes to Jquery or some other languages, val is used as a built in function name.